# PHP zip download bug

Tags: php, android, mobile

I have a script that lets users download a zip file on request. It works 100% on computer browsers but does not work on Android/mobile browsers, except for Opera (mobile) only.

Here's my script.

```
    $leads = new Packer($zip_name);
$index = 1;
$count = 0;
foreach($cLeads->lastUnitInfo['leads'] as $lead)
{
    // build a request string
    $export = 'export_lead_'.$index;
    $req    = $_POST[$export];

    // add it to the zip file
    if(isset($req) && $req == '1')
    {
        // debug only
        //echo 'adding lead: '.$lead['file_name'].'<br />';
        $leads->addLead('leads/'.$lead['file_name'],$lead['item_name']);
        $count++;
        //echo 'count: '.$count.'<br/>';
    }
    $index++;
}

// debug
//exit('count: '.$count);  // displays same results on all browsers.

// we got anything packed ?
if($count <= 0)    //// <-------- BLOCK OF BUG ON MOBILE PHONE
{
    if(file_exists($zip_name))
        unlink($zip_name);  // delete the zip file created.
    exit('<h1>Nothing to export</h1>'); 
}   ///// <---------------------- END BLOCK

// download the leads here.
$leads->purge();
exit;
```

Here's my `purge()` function

```
public function purge($zip_name = 'leads.zip')
  {
    header('Content-type: application/zip');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$zip_name.'"');
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($this->zip_name);

    // errors will be disabled here
    unlink($this->zip_name);
  }
```

On my Android phone, the zip file gets downloaded but contains `<h1>Nothing to export</h1>` which renders it as an invalid zip file.

So my problem is, How is it that the block only executes on mobile browsers (except Opera) and then continues to download the zip when it should have `exited` if `$count` was zero at all?

I debugged it using Fiddler and the requests are all the same but the output is different, why ?

Is this a bug in PHP? Because if you look at my code the function `purge()` should output errors saying headers have already been sent but it just continues to download the zip file.

Browsers:

- Dolphin (+Beta)
- FireFox
- Default Android browser
- Boat Browser

PHP versions tested:

- 5.3.13 (Production, shared server)
- 5.1.4

This is driving me nuts now.

---

@Alix This is the weirdest bug I've ever seen. I don't seriously see any logical errors here. For the script to initiate a download, there actually has to be files added to the zip. Now on my phone, it says no files are added but there's a zip file in the `temp` folder. Moreover if there are no files added (`$count` = 0) then the script should terminate (hence the `exit()` function) with just a message `<h1>Nothing to export</h1>`. But it goes on to download the zip file (which at this time does not exist, but in the temp folder it does). The zip file ends up being corrupt as it contains `<h1>Nothing to export</h1>`

**Alix wrote:**
***> what happens if you comment out the exit call before serving the file?**

It says `readfile` error then purges the zip file in gibberish UNICODE chars. I can tell it's the zip file because it starts with `PK` and contains the names of images being exported.

**Alix wrote:**

> If this doesn't work, you may wanna change `exit('<h1>Nothing to export</h1>');` to exit(var_dump($_REQUEST));, that way you may check for possible bugs in the form submission by inspecting the Zip file.

Interesting. It prints nothing but the cookie and a $_GET parameter only. If I put the code in your suggestion at the beginning on the script and in the block that adds the files to the zip it prints all the `$_POST` variables.

There's clearly a bug on PHP's part here. It should terminate when `exit` is called but it doesn't. And mind you this only happens on mobile browsers except Opera. I'm going to cry blood now.

Comment: Are you sending a cache header of `no-cache`?  It's known for some browsers to cause an issue where the file won't be cached so after downloading it's removed from the users temp directory.

Comment: I added that in hopes of removing the problem. But alas, it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I seem to have the same problem. The downloads work fine on Desktops but android or iOS browser seem to time out with now data download.

Comment: How's your project setup? Like mine?

Comment: Actually my error is slightly different. The download seems to start in the browsers but nothing ever downloads and eventually it times out and you get a download failed error. I am pull files from the same type php code with java and objective-c http requests but the browsers don't seem to work at all. I don't delete the zipfile at the end and I don't believe I used any of the ob commands. I'm wondering if the download being slower than normal internet connection is failing because command is taking too long to execute but I haven't seen that in the logs.

Comment: try disabling or setting your php timeout. `set_time_limit(0)` <--That disables timeout. Also, place logs to see where the code hangs.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the other browsers are setting `$_POST[$export]` to the correct value?

Also, you should first `ob_[end_]clean()` and then output the headers, not the other way around:

```
public function purge($zip_name = 'leads.zip')
  {
    ob_end_clean();
    flush();
    header('Content-Type: application/zip');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$zip_name.'"');
    readfile($this->zip_name);

    // errors will be disabled here
    unlink($this->zip_name);
  }
```

Additionally, you may wanna set these headers:

```
header('Content-Length: ' . intval(filesize($zip_name)));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
```

If this doesn't work, you may wanna change `exit('<h1>Nothing to export</h1>');` to `exit(var_dump($_REQUEST));`, that way you may check for possible bugs in the form submission by inspecting the Zip file.

Comment: `$_POST[$export]` is set. I used this code to check it across all the said browsers.

`exit('count: '.$count)` which resulted in `count: 2`. But what baffles me is that is goes into the block whose expression evaluates to `false` and then invokes `exit()` but does not terminate, rather continues to download the zip file.

Comment: @chx101: I was staring at the code for a while and I can't understand why it might fail on some browsers. I highly doubt it's a PHP bug tho (arithmetic-logic wise would be pretty obvious). Perhaps there's some other code (or order) you're not disclosing? Also, what happens if you comment out the `exit` call before serving the file?